# How is metadata_xml column generated in GeoNode DB?

Tags: postgresql, xml, metadata, geonode, pycsw

There is a *metadata_xml* column in the *base_resourcebase* table of **GeoNode** database. It contains XML document with metadata informations of the layer.

There are also other metadata columns in this table, such as *title*, *abstract*, *license_id* (foreign key), *data_quality_statement*. These informations are duplicit with the informations from XML.

How is the XML document in *metadata_xml* generated?
What is the XML document used for? Can it be omitted?

---

I'm asking this question because I need to transfer metadata from one GeoNode to another with the same layers. I thought it would be enough to update needed columns of *base_resourcebase* and *layers_layer*, joined using *layers_layer.typename*, but the XML document contains details I don't want to change, like *fileIdentifier*, or URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `metadata_xml` field is provided in GeoNode to manage a static rendering of a given layer's metadata record in ISO 19115/19139.  The document is used for fast delivery of the GeoNode native layer model in ISO and as an early out for CSW workflows.

GeoNode refreshes this column internally whenever a user updates their metadata.  The column is required and GeoNode will break if it is omitted.

Check the [docs](http://docs.geonode.org/en/master/tutorials/admin/backup_restore/index.html#backup-restore-geonode) or the [GeoNode users](http://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/geonode-users) mailing list on ways of safely migrating data from / to GeoNode environments.